# Set value of loss function when calculating/applying gradients

Tags: tensorflow

I am using TensorFlow as a part of a larger system where I want to apply the gradient updates in batches. Ideally I'd like to do something along the lines of (in pseudo-code):

```
grads_and_vars = tf.gradients(loss, [vars])
list_of_losses = [2, 1, 3, ...]
for loss_vals in list_of_losses:
   tf.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, feed_dict = {loss : loss_vals}
```

My loss function depends on earlier predictions from my neural network and it takes a long time to compute thus my need for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `tf.gradients`, the argument `grad_ys` let you specify custom values from upstream backprop graph. If you don't specify them, you end up with node that assumes that upstream backprop is tensor of 1's (Fill node). So you could either call `tf.gradients` with a placeholder that lets you specify custom upstream values, or just feed the Fill node.

IE

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
a = tf.constant(2.)
b = tf.square(a)
grads = tf.gradients(b, [a])
sess.run(grads, feed_dict={"gradients/Fill:0": 0})
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP.)*

Thanks for your suggestions Yaroslav! Below is the code I put together based on your suggestions. I think this solves my problem:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    X = tf.placeholder("float", name="X")
    W = tf.Variable(1.0, name="weight")
    b = tf.Variable(0.5, name="bias")
    pred = tf.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.multiply(X, W), b))

    opt = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(1.0)
    gvs = tf.gradients(pred, [W, b], grad_ys=0.5)

    train_step = opt.apply_gradients(zip(gvs, [W, b]))
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    for i in range(50):
        val, _ = sess.run([pred, train_step], feed_dict= {X : 2})
        print(val)
```